# ListBox Selected Items Includes All Items

Tags: wpf, vb.net, checkedlistbox, xceed

After a user clicks on any number of items in a CheckedListBox, I want to programmatically remove the checks on those items when the window is closed. With the CheckedListBox named lstChoices, I have:

```
For I As Integer = 0 To lstChoices.SelectedItems.Count - 1
    Dim lbi As Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.Primitives.SelectorItem = CType(lstChoices.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(I), Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.Primitives.SelectorItem)
    lbi.IsSelected = False
Next
```

The problem is that the SelectedItems property is NOT the selected items.  Oddly, the SelectedItems.Count property is computed correctly but the loop just goes through the first ListBoxItems up to Count whether they are selected or not.

The documentation says the SelectedItems property "Gets the collection of checked items".  Either the documentation is wrong or there's a bug in that control.  How can I get just the checked items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently iterating over the `Items` collection as `ContainerFromIndex` returns an item based on the `Items` property and not the `SelectedItems` property.

You should iterate the `SelectedItems` and use `lstChoices.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem` instead:

```
For index As Integer = 0 To lstChoices.SelectedItems - 1
  Dim selectedItem = lstChoices.SelectedItems(index)
  Dim selectedItemContainer = TryCast(lstChoices.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(selectedItem), Selector)
  selectedItemContainer.IsSelected = False
Next
```

Comment: Marked as answer.  Stated more clearly (for me, anyway), is that the Index of the For...Next loop is NOT over the selected items but over all of the items.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful to make the difference between the elements of SelectedItems and Items.

Try this :

```
 For I As Integer = 0 To lstchoices.SelectedItems.Count - 1
    lstchoices.SetItemCheckState(lstchoices.Items.IndexOf(lstchoices.SelectedItems(I)), CheckState.Unchecked)
 Next
```

Comment: That's for a forms CheckedListBox.  As far as I can tell, there is no equivalent for wpf.  In addition, it does not deal with the issue of SelectedItems not returning the "selected items".